# Out of Memory Exception in java Eclipse

Tags: java, exception, heap-memory

Iam trying a Compiler in my java Eclipse. And I get the error :

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve this?

Compiler compiles up to 185 files out of 414 files and then gets the exception. The memory is 1024M

Comment: What do images have to do with a compiler?

Comment: That should be ample memory usually. Is it always failing on the same file? Is there anything different about the file? (e.g. is it HUGE?)

Comment: BTW - *"185 files"* Are these `.java` files, `.jpg` or something else?  By 'compiler' DYM code compilation?

Comment: no..its MIB files. and my project contains images

Comment: Your error implies Runtime OutOfMemoryError. **You** a saying it **complies** some out of more files. Does your project attempt to run some files **before** it compiles all? Do you describe what happens correctly?

Comment: *"..its MIB files."*  Men in Black?  You've ripped MIB 3 *already?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on <kbd>Run configuration</kbd> in the Eclipse. Choose your **application** or **server** tab (which you want to have more memory size).

In the <kbd>Argument</kbd> tab, write `-Xmx<memory size>`. *memory size* is what you want to set.

Comment: This solves the issue.. But This configuration works in local machine. And when I run the Compiler in another system, the same issue occurs.How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

set your **Virtual Memory Argument**
-Xms128M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M like this